# Python itertools.combinations' results

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

I don't get the number of results I should obtain from that function in the Title, so I'm hoping in your help.

Looking at the Docs
http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations
the number of results should be

> The number of items returned is n! / r! / (n-r)! when 0 <= r <= n or
>   zero when r > n.

And it works for the example in there

> combinations('ABCD', 2) --> AB AC AD BC BD CD

because n! / r! / (n-r)! = 4! / 2! / 2! = 6

But if I try

```
combinations('ABCDEF', 3) --> AB AC AD AE AF BC BD BE BF CD CE CF DE DF EF
```

I get those 15 results.
But n! / r! / (n-r)! = 6! / 3! / (6-3)! = 720 / 6 / 6 = 20

So: the Python Docs told me that I should have 20 results, but I get 15.

Can you please help me understand what I'm missing? Maybe is something in my math, as that formula should be right as it is in the [Wikipedia Combination entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination)

Thanks,
P.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

itertools.combinations should be returning an iterator with 20 items:

```
In [40]: len(list(itertools.combinations('ABCDEF',3)))
Out[40]: 20
```

Note that

```
In [41]: len(list(itertools.combinations('ABCDEF',2)))
Out[41]: 15
```

and the output posted

```
combinations('ABCDEF', 3) --> AB AC AD AE AF BC BD BE BF CD CE CF DE DF EF
```

shows only combinations of 2 letters. So it appears you've computed 
`combinations('ABCDEF', 2)`, not `combinations('ABCDEF', 3)`.

Comment: You are right. My fault. Double fault: one because I wrote "combination('ABCDEF', 3)" but I really tried with 2 instead of 3.
The second fault is for sure with the iterable object I'm using with combinations(). Thanks :-)